# Помогите разобратся с запросом java MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, requests

Нужно построить запрос по двум критериям: Списку ids и поле {"isActive":true}
результат данного запроса - только по списку ids;
`{Page<PostDAO> findAllBylfpostIdIn(List<String> lfpostIds, PageRequest pageRequest);}`

А этого по полю ("isActive": true). Но почему он игнорирует второе условие?
`{
@Query({"isActive":true})
Page<PostDAO> findAllBylfpostIdIn(List<String> lfpostIds, PageRequest pageRequest);
}`

Answer (score 2):

```
@Query("{$and:[{'isActive':true},{lfpostId :{$in:?0}}]}")
Page<PostDAO> findAllBylfpostIdIn(List<String> lfpostIds, PageRequest pageRequest);
```

я нашла ответ. Всем спасибо